# GPU memory latency hiding?

Tags: memory, gpu, latency

How does a kernel's working set like number of registers, affect the GPUs ability to hide memory latencies.

Comment: Are you asking: (1) how using more threads/MP helps hiding memory lookup latency, or (2) how to use registers (per thread) to hide lookup latencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By spreading the lookup latency across a group of parallel threads (warp). Refer to the CUDA Programming Guide in the CUDA SDK for detail